# How to find both integer or decimal in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

Text.RegularExpressions.Regex class in c#, in this class I am trying to find string that contains "years" word within

```
 string s11 ="java developer in new york 2years exp"
```

before i am using

```
Regex = new Regex("(\d+)(years?)");
```

here i am getttig inter value in the given string of s11 like

```
Match match = regex.Match(ss);

if(match.Success)
{
    string s = match.Groups[1];
    string s1 = match.Groups[2];
}
```

but this one only works with integer, if suppose I change my string, like:

```
string s11="java developer in new york 0.10years exp"
```

it stops working.

I want work with both integer or decimal like

```
    string s11="java developer in new york 2years exp"
    string s11="java developer in new york 0.10years exp"
```

can any body give the correct solution for this problem; that is to look for both integer and decimal value.

Thanks 
pradeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours is close; I think if you simply add the optional decimal parts:

```
Regex = new Regex("((?:\d*\.)?\d+)(years?)");
```

Answer (score 1):

What about ?

```
Regex = new Regex("([0-9]?\.?\d+)\s*(years?)");
```

Also, there are a number of tools which let you try them out interactively, like

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/16b9d664-d88c-460e-84a5-700ab40ba452

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
new Regex(@"([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)*years");
```

Also, for future reference, http://regexpal.com/ is a simple tool to test out your regular expressions and http://www.regular-expressions.info gives lots of examples.